# Php page redirection on success else show errors

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, redirect

I have a ecrtst.php which has 3 fields for input, on submit - submit-ecr.php. I need to write the data into a mysql table, validating if there is no blank field. 
When I submit with all values it is working fine, it comes back to ecrtst.php after successful submission, but when I leave a blank field, it is unable to show the errors.

Let me know if we can show errors in javascript or php and then go back to previous page.

**ecrtst.php file:**

```
<?php
$dbservertype='mysql';
$servername='localhost';
$dbusername='hitec';
$dbpassword='!@#';
$dbname='hitec';

connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
{
global $link;
$link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
}
//////// End of connecting to database ////////
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>ECR</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
    $("form:not(.filter) :input:visible:enabled:first").focus();
    });
</script>

</head>

<body document.f1.ecrno.focus();">
<table width="100%"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#026465">
  <tr>
<td><div align="center"><center class="style6">ECR</center>
<center>

<?php
$rowec=mysql_query("SELECT Ecrno FROM ECRHDR_draft WHERE usr='$user'");
$rowec2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rowec);
$rowec3=$rowec2['Ecrno'];
?>
<form name='f1' id='f1'>
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="60"><span class='style5'>ECR No.</span></td>
    <td width="99"><input name="ecrno" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="<?=$rowec3;?>" onchange="showecr(this.value);"></td>
<?php
$rowarea=mysql_query("SELECT Area FROM ACMAST");
$rowarea2=mysql_fetch_assoc($rowarea);
$rowarea3=$rowarea2['Area'];
?>
    <td width="180"><select name='area' onchange="showarea(this.value);">
    <option value='<?=$rowarea3;?>'> <?=$rowarea3;?> <option>
    <option value='Rajajinagar'>Rajajinagar</option>
    <option value='Jayanagar'>Jayanagar</option>
    <option value='Chennai'>Chennai</option>
    </select></td>
<?php $script_dt = date('d/m/Y'); ?>
<td width="72"><span class='style5'>ECR Date:</span></td>
<td width="189"><input name="ecrdate" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" value="<?=$script_dt;?>" onchange="showecrdate(this.value);"> <span class='style5'>(d/m/yyyy)</span>        </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a href="submit-ecr.php" target="_parent" accesskey="s" ><input name="SAVE" type="button" value="SAVE ECR !">
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**submit-ecr.php file:**

```
<?php
ob_start();

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","hitec","@#");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("hitec", $con);

 //-----Checking for blank fields in ECRHDR-draft file. ------------------------//

 $rowexist=mysql_query("select Ecrno from ECRHDR_draft WHERE usr='$user'");
 $data=mysql_fetch_array($rowexist);

  if ($data[Ecrno] <= 0 || $data[Ecrno]='')
  {
  echo "<span class='sty1'><center>DONOT LEAVE EMPTY FIELDS for ECR No.</CENTER><br>    <br></span>";
  echo " <span class='sty1'><center><a href=\"javascript:PreviousPage();\">CLICK HERE TO GO BACK !!!!</a></CENTER></span>";
  }

$URL="http://www.samplesite.info/svga//ecrtst.php";

header('WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate');
header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM', false);
header ('Location:'.$URL);

mysql_close($con);
ob_flush();?>
```

Comment: A redirect stays a redirect. Everything you output before will be lost. What you want to do is to redirect to your form page and provide some information of what went wrong via request parameter, session or whatever. Than you can check for that parameter and print out the error messages. I'm pretty sure, you'll find loads of examples for this on SO or Google.

Comment: @Michael Is there an example which shows similar error handling, after submit. I am unable to get the right example on web.

Comment: The code in the answer below is a good example to start with. It may not work in your frame environment, because I assume you do not update multiple frames after a click on that button. My hint: Don't use frames - they are just bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is a little wacky. Instead of echoing the errors, start a PHP session at the top of the file with `session_start()`, and then store the error messages in the session like `$_SESSION['dberror'] = 'You didn\'t fill out all the fields.';`. 
After you redirect, check on the other page for the error `session_start(); if (isset($_SESSION['dberror'])) { echo $_SESSION['dberror']; unset($_SESSION['dberror']); }`.

Comment: That code alone actually will do it. Put session_start() at the top of each file and put the $_SESSION... line where you currently echo your error. Then put the if statement where you want to output the error on the next page.

Comment: Will try this, but how do I go back to previous page after showing the error ?

Comment: Thanks, but one last query, if I have 2 php files in FRAMES, will this error work. Because i am validating data after you press submit button.

Comment: It should, although frames are bad practice.